# Android Eclipse not showing error force close device

Tags: android, eclipse

As I am new to android I have a doubt on finding the errors.If I run my app error comes on device saying Application has stopped running force close.If I see the error in logcat it shows the link to my error.But what I want is to know what is the error. Logcat redirect to the line where error occurs but I am unable to know the error .How to know what is the error exactly.Can any one help me out..!

This is the logcat error soap object serialization problem i think

```
10-22 09:38:29.194: D/dalvikvm(298): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0016
10-22 09:38:29.194: D/dalvikvm(298): VFY: dead code 0x0018-0072 in Lcom/retailer/client/RetailerActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
10-22 09:38:29.274: I/System.out(298): urn:training/
10-22 09:38:29.274: I/System.out(298): searchCompanyInfo
10-22 09:38:29.274: D/AndroidRuntime(298): Shutting down VM
10-22 09:38:29.304: W/dalvikvm(298): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at com.retailer.client.RetailerActivity.onCreate(RetailerActivity.java:24)
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 09:38:29.314: E/AndroidRuntime(298):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
```

What is this error?

```
10-22 11:21:28.794: D/AndroidRuntime(3285): Shutting down VM
10-22 11:21:28.824: W/dalvikvm(3285): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.androidlogin.androidmysql/com.androidlogin.androidmysql.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.androidlogin.androidmysql.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.androidlogin.androidmysql-1.apk]
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.androidlogin.androidmysql.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.androidlogin.androidmysql-1.apk]
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
10-22 11:21:28.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3285):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: post the error log here. That is the explanation for the error.

Comment: @Trinode Sorry I am not able to get You.

Comment: error log is running but it is not showing the error...!

Comment: Post the logs or the link you are talking about from the logcat that you are getting while the exception occurs. This question is too obscure, to help you.

Comment: @ManNiPandiT please past your logCat here without it not possible to get actual problem.

Comment: @morroko i have posted the logact will you help me out...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use eclipse, go project properties and than build path order and export tab select your jars

Comment: @nurisexgin I did that I already exported ksoap2 jar and created a folder libs and in that ksoap jar files.

Comment: @ManNiPandiT Make sure it is checked. Try to move it to the top as well.

Comment: @Shail Adi -ya just now i did that but now it showing something new in console while running lik this...!  [2013-10-22 10:27:40 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex:                   Multiple dex files define  -                                                                            Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64;
[2013-10-22 10:27:40 - Retailer] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64;

Comment: Duğplicate jars error. Did you include other lib projects? Which libraries did you add your project?

Comment: @nurisezgin other lib projects? I created this from an example but web services i have created and namespace method name and all are correct.

Comment: You have 2  Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64 class in your jars. Maybe first in the ksoap second class in other jars.

Comment: @nuriszgin I added the same jar ksoap created a folder libs and pasted the jar into it.Is that a problem?

Comment: @nuriszgin In my bin folder there are 2 dexedlibs libraries ksoap2 as  "ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies-454ab994b5eed62f603e37e5b7297d85.jar" and  "ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-jar-with-dependencies-cebf420bd13bf52194182d16f6f4d4b9.jar" and i have added another folder in project as libs in that i have ksoap2 jar

Comment: @nuriszgin oh fine thankyou i will delete one and will see wthr it run or not if not wil ask you again keep logged in...!

Comment: @nuriszgin Itrs automaticaly creating the jar i deleted it but same error i delted both but again after i run it same error in console and automaticlly in bin the 2 jars are ther . what to do bossa...!

Comment: Could you make clean and build? If problem is countinue than delete bin folder.

Comment: @nurisezgin Same problem is coming after deleting clean and build .shall i delete the bin folder? will be any problem there if i delete bin?

Comment: bin folder is compile result' s files. bin folder contains dexfiles resources files etc..

Comment: @nurisezgin i deleted the folder bin and reopened eclipse but after u run the app again bin came with those two jar file...!? now what to do

Comment: I explain everything step by step. First you will use only different jars. Second eclipse order and export menu tab contains your private libs and dependencies you could click tick this items. And  than clean build your project. Press run after if you will see Noclassdeffound in your logcat please make update adt and android sdk. After this step if your project not working, I wouldn't explain clearly than say sorry.

Comment: @nuriszgin hehehehee chill down man its fine may be some other error leav it thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this error with the following steps given below.

Solutions:-

- Update you App
- Clear Gmail Storage Data
- Clear App Cache and Data
- Reset App Preferences
- Reset Smartphone Factory Settings

I found these steps with the help of YouTube. 
Here is that link:-

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fx8Fv8RXag8